# Should old questions with a bad style in the way they are asked be improved?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, old-questions

For example, in this question: 
[Cocoa: Quartz, Core Graphics, Context vs View. Oh My!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066373/cocoa-quartz-core-graphics-context-vs-view-oh-my?rq=1) , I feel like the "Oh My" sounds a bit awkward..

A lot of old questions from 2009 or 2010 have strange titles like this. By strange, I mean that they are not asked in an  objective way. 
Is it worth to submit small edits for the grammar of this kind questions ?

Note that english is not my mother tongue.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's *bad* style, and I would oppose an edit that does nothing but take the "Oh my" away.

However, for clarity and searchability, I agree there would be a way to put it better. But for that, the entire thing would need a thorough re-work, say

> Terminology: "context" vs. "view" in Quartz and Core Graphics

(if I understand the question right, which I may not)